# TypeError many-to-many set is prohibited

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a like model, when a user click on a button it generate to 1 like in database. This is the error i get when saving my code: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use image_like.set() instead.

```
class Image(models.Model):
    imageuploader_profile = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    first_upload_image = models.FileField(upload_to ='picmate/%Y/%m/%d/',null=True, blank=True)
    image_caption = models.CharField(max_length=700)
    tag_someone = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null= True)

class Likes(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    image_like = models.ManyToManyField(Image, related_name="likes")
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def save_like(request,pk):
    image_like = get_object_or_404(Image,pk=pk)
    like_img, created = Likes.objects.get_or_create(
        image_like=image_like,
    )
    like_img.likes += 1
    like_img.save()
    return redirect('site:home')
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the errors says, you can not just create a `Like` object with:

```
Likes.objects.get_or_create(
    image_like=image_like,
)
```

since a `ManyToManyField` acts like a collection.

It however does *not* seems to make much sense to do that anyway. Likely you need a `ForeignKey` here that refers to an `Image`:

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image, related_name='likes')
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

Then you can implement the view as:

```
def save_like(request,pk):
    image_like = get_object_or_404(Image, pk=pk)
    like_img, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(
        image_id=pk,
        user=request.user
    )
    if not created:
        like_img.likes += 1
        like_img.save()
    return redirect('site:home')
```

You can then count the number of likes for an `Image` object by summing up the `likes` of the related `Like` objects.

Note that if a user can only like an `Image` once, then you can drop the `likes` field, and the logic in the `if` statement.